# Conditional reactive execution of Mono in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a method that returns the count of an entity from DB based on a condition, let's say that the method returns a `Mono<Long>` and it's called as `repository.count()` if the count is 1 I want to call method `A` , if the count is > 1 I want to call method `B` . I want to avoid using something like `repository.count().flatmap(count -> if (count == 1L) return A(); if (count > 1L) return B(); (...) }` instead I want to use `.filter()` or `filterWhen()` but I can't quite wrap my head around how those should be used... Could you please point me in the right direction of how my code should look?

Comment: Why do you want to use filter? Its not what it is designed for. You will still need an if-statement

Answer (score 1):

`filter()` and its variants can only ever *remove* items (or in the case of `Mono`, the single item) from a stream. There's no way they can map them to another value - and even if you *could* achieve this somehow, your reactive stream would be very hard to read, as you'd essentially be misusing an operator.

`map()` or `flatMap()` (depending on whether you want a synchronous or asynchronous mapping) are exactly the *right* way to do things here. Granted the `if` statement doesn't look too neat, but if you want to avoid that just use a ternary:

```
.flatMap(count -> count==1 ? A() : B())
```

...rather than trying to misuse an operator to avoid it. Code similar to the above is commonplace in reactive streams, there's no need to go to great lengths to try to avoid it.

Comment: Believe me that many of us who struggle with the reactive streams are deeply missing something like `.if(condition, publisher-if-true)`, `.if(condition, publisher-if-true, publisher-if-false)`. It is being constantly rejected for reasons which never persuaded me :( E.g. https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/1186 . The code you are suggesting in your answer is correct, but ugly, it kind of doesn't fit the overall concept.